# PHP script execute show results during execution

Tags: php, apache

How can I make that when I execute PHP script from my browser on webserver it shows results of that script while it's still executing (the code has many curls and it takes about 30 minutes to fully process). I have two servers and on one it shows every "echo" when it's called, but on the other server it shows all after 30 minutes, when script is fully executed. Both servers are running on apache, php 5.6
code:

```
<?php
error_reporting('E_ALL');
ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL');
set_time_limit ( 2);

$i=0;
$handle = fopen("filmyNasze.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $line = explode("##", $line);
        $nazwafilmu = trim($line[0]);
        $linkfilmu = trim($line[1]);
        $linkfilmu = 'http://xxx.pl' . $linkfilmu;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $linkfilmu); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: cda.player=html5"));
        curl_exec($ch);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc2 = new DOMDocument();
        $doc2->loadHTML($result);
        $divid = str_replace('/video/', '', trim($line[1]));
        foreach( $doc2->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div ) { 
            if($div->getAttribute('id') == 'mediaplayer' . $divid) {
                $array = json_decode($div->getAttribute('player_data'), true);
                //echo $array["video"]["file"] . " ## ";                    
            }
        }
        echo $nazwafilmu . ' ## ' . trim($line[1]) . ' ## ' . $array["video"]["file"] . '<br />';
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
else {
    die('brak pliku .txt');
}
```

Comment: Prolly won't work due to browser inconsistencies but try the [`flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) functions.

Comment: flush doesn't help here

Answer (score 0):

You can flush PHP's output buffer using `ob_flush()` and `flush()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    echo 'Something';
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: I already used them and they don't work. Script works fine on one server but on second it doesn't. Even when I have HTML code on start of the file (<html><head></head><body>test</body></html>) and then PHP code it doesn't show "test". Both servers are running apache so I thought it would be a problem with it's configuration or something to do with php configuration.

Comment: @monster1777 If it doesn't even print the static HTML at the beginning of the page, then you probably have a syntax error somewhere. Try looking at your Apache logs.

Comment: In apache logs there are no errors. Like I said the very same script works on other webserver, the flush method doesn't work. But when I make an error in the script on purpose it doesn't show in apache logs and not even in browser (I have error reporting on). Well I guess I have to contact my VPS provider

Comment: Also now when I see that when I add to the script ob_start() somewhere it doesn't work on the second server (where it worked without flush perfectly). Maybe it has to do something with and I have to end flush on begginning of script?